# Entity Framework Models

Tags: entity-framework, oop, database-design

I'm using Entity Framework 6.

I'm curious what is the reason for most entities I've seen around to contain their father entity.

Example:

Say I have the following models:

```
public interface IBaseEntityObject 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}


public abstract class BaseEntityObject : IBaseEntityObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Folder : BaseEntityObject
{   
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public List<Letter> Letters {get; set;} 
}


public abstract class Letter : BaseEntityObject
{   
    [DataMember]
    public string Title {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Content {get; set;}

    public virtual Folder Folder {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public int FolderId {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
}

public class OutgoingLetter : Letter
{
    // .. OutgoingLetter properties
}

public class ReceviedLetter : Letter
{
    // .. ReceviedLetter properties
}
```

I've seen this in all examples and demos of EF - containing the father model inside the child object - in my models it refers to contains Folder inside a letter. This seems logically incorrect to me, and break the oop design style.

Is there a specific reason for this? Because both me and my teammates are disturbed by this models design

Comment: Containment is at the heart of OOP http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter8/node9.html

Comment: But isn't it overkill to send the folder to the clients as well?

Answer (score 1):

Link from child to parent allows you to query child by parent data. For example in your case:

```
var lettersFromFolderOne = dbContext.Letters
    .Where(letter => letter.Folder.CreationDate == DateTime.Now)
    .ToList();
```

So look at it from db tables perspective and how you may need to build a query.

Comment: But it makes more sense to do : 
Folders.Find(1).Letters;


Moreover, when I return letters to client through http, I dont want them to receive the entire folder

Comment: Well, there are many ways to skin a cat but I just wanted to say that reference from child to parent can be used in linq queries that way and it is often used.

Comment: Isn't it overkill to send the folder as well to the clients?

Comment: You can send anything you need, you can only send folder name like .Select(a=>a.Name).ToList() or select result into lightweight object.

Comment: Good point. Is there a preformance loss if I remove the Virtual Folder property?